# Реализация промежуточного менеджера между ядром и пользовательским приложением

Tags: c++, многопоточность, шаблоны-проектирования, многоагентная-система

Есть некоторая многоагентная система, которая имеет ядро, агентную сеть, сервисы и проч.

Она загружается и управляется посредством менеджера, назовем его `System_Manager`.

Также через него осуществляется общение с пользовательским приложением, т.е. этот менеджер владеет объектом сконструированного ядра, к которому пользовательское приложение через него и обращается. Также он ответственен за удаление и сохранение.

Вопрос возник в реализации этого менеджера. Реализовывать его синглтонным образом? Возникла проблема с вызовом удалителя, т.е. в многопоточном пользовательском приложении не будет вполне понятно, когда его вызвать, возможно, какому-то потоку потребуется доступ к ядру, а другой его уже закроет (удалит). С другой стороны, если разрешить создание нескольких экземпляров, то концептуально это выглядит странно. По сути эти экземпляры будут идентичны, позволить каждому иметь копию ядра нельзя -> ядро рассматривается как статический объект-член класса, опять же непонятно, кто его удалит. Тут придется что-то с подсчетом кол-ва соединений (текущих созданных экземпляров) делать.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как реализовывать такой сервис?

Comment: Да, совершенно согласен, Вы абсолютно правы!

Comment: Уточните, менеджер линкуется с приложением или это независимый процесс с которым приложение обменивается сообщениями (используя сокеты, общую память и т.п.)?

Comment: @avp - линкуется. По сути - интерфейсный модуль в приложении, предоставляющий доступ пользовательскому коду (mt) к ядру и его сервисам (mt).

Comment: Если это просто интерфейсный модуль, то о каком удалении (и прочем функционале, не связанным с реализацией интерфейса) идет речь? О закрытии канала связи с ядром? Тогда, наверное, счетчик ссылок. Но, без понимания архитектуры в целом, советы давать, сами понимаете, трудно.

Answer (score 0):

Я придерживаюсь такой концепции. 
Инстанс `System_Manager` создается в `main()`, в тот момент когда это удобно, можно и на стеке. Потом "запускает" основной код, например, `app.exec()`  или что-то подобное, который имеет ссылку на `System_Manager`. Затем по нажатию пользователем кнопочки [X] или командый "quit" полученой другим способом, вызывает "shutdown" у `System_Manager` для мягкого завершения всех сервисов или перевод их в безопастный режим, заметем выходим из `app.exec()`, после чего дожидаемся завершения всех потоков, которые связаны с `System_Manager`, и разрушаем его.